# PHP MSSQL fail on update query

Tags: java, php, sql-server

I am having this store procedure on mssql

```
alter procedure loginmember
    @user varchar(100),
    @pass varchar(100)
as
set nocount on
    if exists (select 1 from member where username=@user and pass=@pass)
    begin
        select 1 as res
        update memberStatus set isLogin=1 where username=@user
    end
    else
    begin
        select 0 as res
    end
set nocount off
```

and the table are member (having username and password field) an memberStatus (username, isLogin -int-)

my query is
exec loginmember 'admin','asdasdasd'

in mssql and java,, the isLogin was change from 0 to 1,, but not in the php

here the php code

```
$sql="exec loginmember '".$_POST['Username']."','".$_POST['password']."'";
$result=sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if($result){
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC);
    if($row[0]===1){
        $redirect=true;
    } else {
        $wrongPass=true;
    }
}
```

I've got no problem with connection and the $redirect was change to true, but isLogin not updated... somebody please help me...

Comment: select both the parameters inside procedure and check whether values are passed to it. `select 1 as res,@user,@pass`

Comment: @VR46, I am pretty sure the values are passed since to get the select 1 as res I have check it in if exists (select 1 from member where username=@user and pass=@pass), and yeah I do what you suggest to make sure... and still the isLogin isn't changed